# Инициализация std::array в библиотеке stl

Tags: c++, stl

Почему при инициализации `std::array` необходимо задавать размер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с C++17 размер [можно не задавать](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WNLci0AjmxOroaqk):

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 2> a = {1,2}; // до C++17
    std::array b = {1,2};         // С++17 и выше
}
```

Эта возможность основана на [Class Template Argument Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (CTAD).

А в C++20 ещё добавили `std::to_array`, где можно при необходимости указать тип элементов, если он отличается от выведенного автоматически:

```
auto c = std::to_array<long>({1,2});
```

Размер при этом так же указывать не надо.

Comment: Тем не менее, размер по-прежнему задается при инициализации...

Comment: @user7860670 если так рассуждать, то и для `auto` тип задаётся. Но мы же понимаем о чём речь, ведь так?

Comment: Да, для auto тип по-прежнему задается **при инициализации**, разница только в том, что он выводится. В С++ вообще нельзя создать переменную не задав тип сразу тем или иным образом. Это очень существенное свойство языка, контрастирующее с другими языками, где можно задавать тип переменной потом или выводить его из контекста последующего использования переменной.

Comment: @user7860670 конечно, во многих вопросах на SO можно углядеть недостаточную однозначность формулировок. Однако, в данном случае я считаю (и, видимо, не безосновательно, раз галочка стоит), что речь о необходимости **явного** упоминания размера, а не выведенного. Например, на контрасте выведения размера при инициализации сырого массива. Про какую-то run-time составляющую размера `std::array` речи не шло.